# How to track child process using strace?

Tags: linux, multithreading, strace

I used `strace` to attach to a process briefly. The process created 90 threads. When I found the offending thread, I had to tediously search for the parent thread, then the grandparent thread, and so on all the way to the root process.

Is there a trick or tool to quickly figure out which thread created another? Or better yet, print the tree of thread creations like `pstree`?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

`strace -f` to trace child process that's `fork()`ed.

Comment: It's worth noting though that if you are attaching strace to an already running process, any _existing_ child processes are not traced even with `-f`

Answer (score 31):

I can't see an easy way:

You could use the `-ff` option with `-o filename` to produce multiple files (one per pid).

eg:

```
strace -o process_dump -ff ./executable
grep clone process_dump*
```

that would help you see which parent created what. Maybe that would help you - at least then you could search backwards.

Answer (score 26):

There is a perl script called `strace-graph`.  Here is a [version from github](https://github.com/strace/strace/blob/master/src/strace-graph).  It is packaged with **crosstool-ng** versions of compilers.  It works for me even used cross platform.

There is also a more [modern python3 script](https://github.com/mgedmin/strace-process-tree). It can be installed on Debian/Ubuntu (and many other systems) with `pip3 install strace-process-tree`.

The process below to capture data is the same for both (but use `strace-process-tree` instead to create the graph). <sup>Thanks [Jan Tojnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/160386/jan-tojnar)</sup>

It seems the perl script may suffer from bit rot.  For a cross platform solution with older busybox type `ps`, it may work.

---

## ARM Linux box.

```
$ ./strace -f -q -s 100 -o app.trc -p 449
$ tftp -pr app.trc 172.0.0.133
```

## X86_64 Linux box.

```
$ ./strace-graph /srv/tftp/app.trc 
 (anon)
  +-- touch /tmp/ppp.sleep
  +-- killall -HUP pppd
  +-- amixer set Speaker 70%
  +-- amixer set Speaker 70%
  +-- amixer set Speaker 70%
  +-- amixer set Speaker 70%
  +-- amixer set Speaker 50%
  +-- amixer set Speaker 70%
  `-- amixer set Speaker 50%
```

The output can be used to help navigate the main trace log.

---

## strace-process-tree example

```
$ strace -f -q -o app.trc sh -c 'for i in `seq 0 10` ; do /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"; done;'
$ strace-process-tree -A -C app.trc
356 sh -c 'for i in `seq 0 10` ; do /usr/bi...'
  |-357 seq 0 10
  |-358 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-359 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-360 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-361 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-362 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-363 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-364 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-365 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-366 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  |-367 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
  `-368 /usr/bin/echo "Hello There"
```

Comment: very nice, this is almost exactly something i wanted for at least several days. surprisingly, i can even see it in my /usr/share/doc/strace/examples/.

Comment: Actually, looks like the Perl script is considered broken upstream: https://github.com/strace/strace/commit/5685c0d0335246b37c57e65303c82206bdd45e65

Answer (score 1):

To capture traffic for a single process you can use `strace`, as @stackmate suggested.

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 -p <PID>;
```

or output it to a file.

```
strace -f -e trace=network -s 10000 -o dumpfile -p <PID>
```

`-f` for all forked process, `-s` for string size to print, and `-o` to dump the output to a file.