# Python multiprocessing subclass initialization

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Is it okay to initialize the state of a `multiprocessing.Process` subclass in the `__init__()` method?  Or will this result in duplicate resource utilization when the process forks?  Take this example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe
import time

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, conn, bar):
        super().__init__()
        self.conn = conn
        self.bar = bar
        self.databuffer = []

    def foo(self, baz):
        return self.bar * baz

    def run(self):
        '''Process mainloop'''
        running = True
        i = 0
        while running:
            self.databuffer.append(self.foo(i))
            if self.conn.poll():
                m = self.conn.recv()
                if m=='get':
                    self.conn.send((i, self.databuffer))
                elif m=='stop':
                    running = False
            i += 1
            time.sleep(0.1)


if __name__=='__main__':
    conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = MyProcess(child_conn, 5)
    p.start()      
    time.sleep(2)

    # Touching the instance does not affect the process which has forked.
    p.bar=1
    print(p.databuffer)

    time.sleep(2)
    conn.send('get')
    i,data = conn.recv()
    print(i,data)
    conn.send('stop')
    p.join()
```

As I note in the code, you cannot communicate with the process via the instance `p`, only via the `Pipe` so if I do a bunch of setup in the `__init__` method such as create file handles, how is this duplicated when the process forks?

Does this mean that subclassing `multiprocessing.Process` in the same way you would a `threading.Thread` a bad idea?

Note that my processes are long running and meant to handle blocking IO.

Answer (score 2):

This is easy to test. In `__init__`, add the following:

```
 self.file = open('does_it_open.txt'.format(self.count), 'w')
```

Then run:

```
 $ strace -f python youprogram.py 2> test.log
 $ grep does_it_open test.log
 open("does_it_open.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 6
```

That means that at least on my system, copying your code and adding that call, the file was opened once, and only once.

For more about the wizardry that is `strace`, check out [this fantastic blog post](http://jvns.ca/blog/2014/04/20/debug-your-programs-like-theyre-closed-source/).

Comment: I think that `strace` is only looking at the main process. When I move the `open()` call to the `run()` method it does not show up in `strace`.

Comment: Good catch. Add the `-f` flag to [include forked processes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6314744/344286).

Comment: Appending `os.getpid()` to the filename does confirm that the file is only opened up once. This makes sense since the file handle can be passed to the new process without trouble. I don't believe that the processes share any memory though, so is any memory I allocate in the constructor duplicated?

Comment: You don't allocate memory. You might create new objects, but you don't allocate memory. If you look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class you'll see that the whole point of the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block is to prevent that code from running in forked processes - either via threading or multiprocessing.

Comment: It looks like process is forked by default (on Linux at least) so the `__name__` check should not come into play. If I were to allocate memory in the parent process prior to calling `p.start()` then that data will simply be memory mapped to the fork until it is written. From my understanding of fork, there will be a copy of the data structure when I try to write to it. Not sure if the copy is partial or total.

Comment: You don't _instantiate_ your class outside your `__name__ == '__main__'`. Defining a class doesn't take (much) memory, and certainly `__init__` is never called.